# Adding relative path as aa variable

Tags: python-3.x, path, os.path

I want to get user input path and use it as a variable. But still struggle to use it right way. I put root variable for error_log creation in the folder by User input.

```
root = input("Enter path to music folder: ")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        if name.lower().endswith(".mp3"):
            try:
                os.rename(os.path.join(root,name), os.path.join(root,name.replace("_"," ").replace(".MP3",".mp3")))
            except:
                with open(r"root\Error_mp3_log.txt","a", encoding='UTF-8') as w:
                    w.write(os.path.join(root, name, "\n"))
                    w.write('\n')
```

Comment: As a side note, you may want to look into using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) from the standard library instead of doing your own path manipulations on strings.

Comment: Struggle in what way? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @ekhumoro so this program replace all underscores in mp3 file names. I ask user for mp3 folder path and use this path as a variable here: 
with open(r"root\Error_mp3_log.txt","a", encoding='UTF-8') as w:
But I red a lot of articles and didn't figure it out.